# AFTER INSERT, UPDATE Trigger won't update when importing data

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update, insert-update

I ideally want this trigger for a table where the clients' data get imported from an Excel spreadsheet. In some cases the names are all CAPITALIZED and I have the Function that updates them to lower case except first letter, first letter after apostrophe and etc. which I'm invoking it in the trigger. Following is my Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CapString] ( @InputString varchar(4000) ) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN    
DECLARE @Index          INT
DECLARE @Char           CHAR(1)
DECLARE @PrevChar       CHAR(1)
DECLARE @OutputString   VARCHAR(255)

SET @OutputString = LOWER(@InputString)
SET @Index = 1

WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
BEGIN
    SET @Char     = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)
    SET @PrevChar = CASE WHEN @Index = 1 THEN ' '
                         ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index - 1, 1)
                    END
    IF @PrevChar IN (' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&', '''', '(')
    BEGIN
        IF @PrevChar != '''' OR UPPER(@Char) != 'S'
            SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString, @Index, 1, UPPER(@Char))
    END
  SET @Index = @Index + 1
END    
RETURN @OutputString
END
```

Following is my Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Test_UpdateTrigger] 
    ON [dbo].[Test]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
        UPDATE [dbo].[Test]
    SET FName = dbo.CapString(FName),
        LName =  dbo.CapString(LName)
        WHERE JuncID IN (SELECT JuncID FROM Inserted)
```

So, my problem is, it does update upper case letters to lower case when I insert clients manually using SELECT statement or the GUI. It doesn't do anything when I import data from excel. Is there anything I'm doing wrong or needs to be done in this case? Thanks!

Comment: *How* are you importing from Excel

Comment: @podiluska I use Management Studio to import. Right Click on DB => Tasks => Import Data... then follow the wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers are disabled by default when using `bcp` or `bulk insert`.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187640(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187640%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Use

```
bcp -h "FIRE_TRIGGERS"
```

or

```
BULK INSERT FIRE_TRIGGERS
```

Comment: Thanks much, it's a very helpful information. If you hint how I'd use `BULK INSERT FIRE_TRIGGERS` within my Trigger it will be wonderful. Many thanks!

Comment: You use it on your import, not on the trigger. It's a setting of the import mechanism.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help on this. So... we also have an import feature set up in front end for users to import and it looks like it works using that GUI.

Answer (score 1):

The "Import Data…" option in SSMS uses the Import and Export Data tool which, in turn, creates and runs an SSIS package for you. In order to get SSIS to fire triggers on an OLEDB destination, you have to go through some hoops. But they're detailed [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141237.aspx) (search for "FIRE_TRIGGERS").